# Where should i place "piece" when talking about it being from a collection?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I came across the following sentence, and I'm not sure if I should change it or it is grammatically fine as it is. Let's say `BRAND` is a brand of jewelry such as Pandora, Tiffany, etc..

> I am looking to buy a BRAND Jewelry piece for her birthday！

Is this the proper way to use `piece`? In respect to it being from a collection? Or should i say: `I am looking to buy a piece from BRAND's line of jewelry for her birthday`?

I only say this as this is the way I would say it, and the original sentence I just feel is wrong, but I cant find any definitive proof to make my claim. If there is another way to properly state this sentence, I am also interested in how.

Answer (score 1):

I personally would say

> I am looking to buy a piece of BRAND jewelry for her birthday.

By placing "piece" after "jewelry" you're using BRAND to describe a "jewelry piece", which doesn't exist.

Your second sentence is more elegant but needs to be corrected as follows:

> I am looking to buy a piece of jewelry from BRAND's line for her birthday

since the 'focus' is on the "piece of jewelry", not the "BRAND's line".